# Jobseeker vs job seeker – is there a difference in meaning?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Online dictionaries define a job seeker as *a person who is unemployed and looking for work* and a jobseeker as *someone who is trying to find a job*.

Is the unemployment factor important here? Does the first term encompass people who are looking for a job even if they do have one currently and aren't unemployed? Are these synonymous or does the split spelling change the meaning?

I am looking for a term to describe all people who are looking for jobs, regardless of the fact if they're unemployed or just looking to change jobs.

Comment: What's the difference between "looking for work" and "trying to find a job"? They mean the same thing, dictionaries give their own take (definitions) on the meanings of words, expressions, idioms etc. In that definitions are  the same but said in slightly different ways.

Comment: Which online dictionaries specifically? If both definitions were given by the same one you have an interesting premise for the question :)

Comment: I used Cambridge, Collins, and some other ones. The two definitions were not given by the same dictionary. I'm just extra-careful :D

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that **jobseeker** is written as one word, and **job seeker** is written as two words. They mean exactly the same.

Although many people will suppose that a 'jobseeker' is someone who is unemployed, this is not always the case. They may have a part-time or full-time job already.

In the UK the government pays something called 'Jobseeker's Allowance' (written like that) and people who work 16 hours a week or less may claim it.

Some online dictionaries are not very good. Cambridge is a good one, and tells you that 'jobseeker' and 'job seeker' (also 'job hunter') all mean 'someone who is trying to find a job'.

[Job seeker meaning (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/job-seeker)

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael!